# GWTTestCase timeout in Jenkins

Tags: gwt, maven, gwttestcase

When I kick off a Jenkins job that runs a GWTTestCase through Maven, the job fails randomly with the same exception.  I can't reproduce this behavior in Eclipse.  Below is the exception.

```
<testcase time="300.144" classname="client.gdo.model.impl.GwtTestLevelOfDetailDefinition" name="testGetAttributesAfterJsonParse">
    <error message="The browser did not complete the test method WebFrameworkClientTest.JUnit:client.gdo.model.impl.GwtTestLevelOfDetailDefinition.testGetAttributesAfterJsonParse in 300000ms.
  We have no results from:
161.134.22.175 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
Actual time elapsed: 300.144 seconds.
Try increasing this timeout using the &apos;-testMethodTimeout minutes&apos; option
" type="com.google.gwt.junit.client.TimeoutException">com.google.gwt.junit.client.TimeoutException: The browser did not complete the test method WebFrameworkClientTest.JUnit:client.gdo.model.impl.GwtTestLevelOfDetailDefinition.testGetAttributesAfterJsonParse in 300000ms.
  We have no results from:
161.134.22.175 / Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19
Actual time elapsed: 300.144 seconds.
Try increasing this timeout using the &apos;-testMethodTimeout minutes&apos; option

at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.notDone(JUnitShell.java:1031)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1381)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTestImpl(JUnitShell.java:1309)
at com.google.gwt.junit.JUnitShell.runTest(JUnitShell.java:653)
at com.google.gwt.junit.client.GWTTestCase.runTest(GWTTestCase.java:441)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because depending of your architecture, `GWTTestCase` can be very long to execute.

Try augmenting the timeout as indicated in the error log.

Comment: The tests take 6 seconds to run in Eclipse.  It shouldn't require more than 5 minutes to run in any other environment.

Comment: OK. Your lag states that you have a timeout during the execution of `testGetAttributesAfterJsonParse`. Can you provide the code of this test ? (or a relevant snippet) ?

Comment: The test extends GWTTestCase and just does a JsonUtils.safeEval() on a simple short string.